# Can't deploy dockerized app to heroku, because I'm getting "Expected response to be successful, got 404" error

Tags: python, docker, heroku

I managed to put my django app on Heroku, and now I want to try the same with the dockerized version. Almost at the end of the process I got an error and can't find a solution anywhere. When I input the command "heroku container:release web" I get "Expected response to be successful, got 404" What did i do wrong? Is something wrong with how i set up port?

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /demo-project
WORKDIR /demo-project
COPY . /demo-project/

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && apk del build-deps
```

## Procfile

```
web: gunicorn demo_project.wsgi -b :${PORT}
```